# Python Selenium TimeoutException error even with wait until clickable and except TimeoutException:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, timeoutexception

My selenium webdriver been constantly crashing  due to

> TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from
> renderer: 298.972

The cookies pop up opens up but the script doesn't click on it,
in like 20 `driver.get(url)`, 19 times it will accept cookies but the 20th will fail to accept cookies, although the window has opened up, I tried to use the code below but still fails.

```
retries = 1
while retries <= 5:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="coi-banner__accept"]'))) #wait until cookies clickable
        element.click()
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.refresh()            
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="coi-banner__accept"]'))) #wait until cookies clickable
        element.click()
        retries += 1
```

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: @Prophet novasol.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the below script more than 20 times and still it was able to click on the desired button every single time.

All I had to do was basically to change the locator to CSS from XPath:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.novasol.com/")

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick='CookieInformation.submitAllCategories();']"))).click()
    print('Clicked it')
except:
    print('Either element was not found, or Bot could not click on it.')
    pass
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Updated:**

```
driver.get("https://www.novasol.com/")

def retry_click(number_of_retries, wait_before_performing_click):
    while number_of_retries > 0:
        time.sleep(wait_before_performing_click)
        try:
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick='CookieInformation.submitAllCategories();']"))).click()
            break
        except:
            pass
        number_of_retries = number_of_retries - 1


try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick='CookieInformation.submitAllCategories();']"))).click()
    print('Clicked it')
except:
    print('Either element was not found, or Bot could not click on it.')
    driver.refresh()
    retry_click(20, 10)
    pass
```

Comment: Used this, but this time it failed to accept cookies at the 17th try : TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 298.955, maybe how could I add in except to refresh the link and try find the element again?

Comment: @Skittles: Updated, see above. if that still shows the issue, we would have to put a max_retry var and keep on retrying until we get succeed.

Comment: thank you, tried the updated code, but again failed on get(URL) 5th try, I could try to run it again because it doesn't fail every time, but would like to solve it that it works every time.

Comment: Need to create a function that will keep on retrying after a specified time and only exit once it's available to click.

Comment: could you please help with that how to write that? I tried to write in except :  driver.quit( ), driver.get(link), wait.until.. but that didn't do anything.

Comment: @Skittles: See above, I have updated again. Hope this helps now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use driver.execute_script() instead of element.click()

```
htmlElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="coi-banner__accept"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", htmlElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally,

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="coi-banner__accept"]'))) #wait until cookies clickable
element.click()
```

should work. From the code you shared I can't see why it works in 95% cases but fails in 5% case.
What I do see:
You are trying to find exactly the same condition in `except` block that caused the `TimeoutException`.
So, if somehow Selenium could not find element matching this locator `//*[@class="coi-banner__accept"]` to be clickable and thrown an `TimeoutException` waiting for the same condition in `except` will give you the same result....
Also, I see no sense to put this in a loop of 5 attempts.
In case element was found, clicked and closed - no sense to try again.
And in case you could not do that in the first attempt - this will throw you `TimeoutException` exception on the first attempt, you will never continue to the second attempt here...

Comment: for some reason sometimes it doesn't recognize the cookies pop up, I wanted to add in except: refresh the browser/link and try to find the element again.

Comment: OK, with refresh it should work.